# How to : python string parsing with whitespaces, except single space between words?

Tags: python, string, iptables

Been working on parsing iptables output to get the stats per source IP usin python. Did not want to include iptc module.
So just doing string manipulations.

```
bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0            udp  --  *      eth1    10.10.10.10          0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:10 
        0     0            tcp  --  *      eth1    10.10.10.10          0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:10 
        0     0            all  --  *      eth1    1.1.1.1              0.0.0.0/0           
        0     0            all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           source IP range 5.5.5.5-5.5.5.10 
        0     0            all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           source IP range 4.4.4.4-4.4.4.5 
        0     0            all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0          

>>> s='    0     0            udp  --  *      eth1    10.10.10.10          0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:10 '
>>> s.split()
['0', '0', 'udp', '--', '*', 'eth1', '10.10.10.10', '0.0.0.0/0', 'udp', 'spt:10']
```

want to parse as below, how do I seperate all the spaces except single space between words ?

```
expected_output=['0', '0', 'udp', '--', '*', 'eth1', '10.10.10.10', '0.0.0.0/0', 'udp spt:10']
```

OR is there a better to get stats from iptables, but without iptc ?

Comment: You could use `re.split`: `re.split(' {2,}', s)`. Don't know if there's a better solution, though.

Comment: Are you sure these blocks are not tab-separated? If they were, you could just do `s.split('\t')` without issue.

Comment: its output of "iptables -t -nvL",

Answer (score 1):

It is not guaranteed that all columns would be separated by more than one space for the iptables output. It just guarantees that there is at least one space. Following is a snippet from that command's output (when run on one of my machines), and you can see that happening:

```
 $> iptables -nvL
 ...
     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 ...
```

Fortunately, the values in first 9 columns will not have any spaces. So you can do the following for each line to get the data in the way you want:

```
fs = s.split()
if len(fs) > 9:
     fs[9] = " ".join(fs[9:])
     fs = fs[:10]
```